# How to show 0 when no row found

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query in which I am passing sysdate to the query problem is that when there is no matching date in table with sysdate then it don't shows the zero even if there is nvl applied
 here is my query

```
select * from molasses
where trunc(trn_dte) = trunc(sysdate)
```

But it show data only when current date is present in table but I want to show zero if no data found in table.please help me to do this in oracle 10 g. Because some times the situation is like above and I have to display zero when no data found

Comment: You want `0` in all columns? Some columns will have other (than numeric) datatypes.

Comment: Can't you just check in your application that 0 rows are returned?

Comment: I want to show 0 when no data found in table against sysdate

Comment: And the `trn_date` column? Is that numeric too?

Comment: no this is date type and i will select only numeric columns when i got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird and I wouldn't use it, it's more of a hack:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN              --- numeric columns
FROM molasses
WHERE trunc(trn_dte) = trunc(sysdate)

UNION ALL

SELECT 0, 0, ..., 0
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM molasses
         WHERE trunc(trn_dte) = trunc(sysdate)
      ) ;
```

One only wonders what the application/user will understand when there is exactly one row in the table and all the values are zero.

---

I think this would work, too:

```
SELECT m.col1, m.col2, ..., m.colN              --- numeric columns
FROM dual LEFT JOIN molasses m
  ON trunc(m.trn_dte) = trunc(sysdate) ;
```

and show Nulls instead of (the wanted) 0s. Using the `COALESCE()` function could easily fix that, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this *would* work, but I don't think it is a very good idea:

```
select nvl(t.a, n.a) as a, nvl(t.b, n.b) as b, ...
from molasses t
right outer join (select 0 as a, 0 as b, ... from dual) n on 1 = 1
```

Comment: Why not? SQL has all the power to let us choose to put the handling of the not-found case on the application side or the SQL side (maybe in a stored procedure). It depends on our use case (maybe this specific one is not good).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very unusual question. Why should a query return 0's when no data present? Usually it's up to the client software/report generator to show something meaningful when no data is present, not the query itself.

Comment: View the above answers Please

Comment: @user1685991 - you've got multiple experienced developers telling you this is a bad idea - not an impossible thing to do, but a bad idea nonetheless.  Caveat programmor...

Comment: for example if i am looking for a month report then missing of any dates confuse me so i want to show all days if there is no any rows for that day then zero is OK for me instead of missing a day in month report.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has four numeric columns, you could write:

```
select * from molasses
where trunc(trn_dte) = trunc(sysdate)
union all
select 0, 0, 0, 0 from dual
where ( select count(*) from molasses where trunc(trn_dte) = trunc(sysdate) ) = 0
```